# Eclipse debugger does not continue after readLine()

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse for an android application. I'm starting two emulators and sending a message between them. There is a server running on both of them and a new message creates a client socket and sends the message over it.

I can't see the message being received by the server. And when I debug step by step, it doesn't proceed after the in.readLine() call, it just says "stepping": https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0CWm.png (The code you see in the image is the server code).

Can anybody tell me what is happening and what I can do to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the readLine() method blocks until it finds an EOL character, or the end of the stream has been reached. Make sure the client actually sends an EOL character or closes its socket.